# How do I stop it from returning "\n" along with data in the list?

Tags: python, arrays, file-handling

```
def register(string):
  userpass = string.split(" ")
  k7 = userpass[0]
  k2 = userpass[1]
  users.append[k7]
  passes.append[k2]
  return "Registered!"
```

don't worry about this part ^^^ it's just an unused function that I'll use soon.

```
users = []
passes = []

csvfile = open('upassword.csv', 'r', encoding= 'utf-8')
for i in csvfile:
  x = i.split(',')
  if x[0] != 'username':
    print('username: ', x[0])
    users.append(x[0])
  if x[1] != 'password':
    print('password:', x[1])
    passes.append(x[1])
```

So here, I am printing the list just to test out how the values come out from the csv file and when I append and print them to some lists in the code, the first password returns with '\n' at the end of its data string which I can't remove for some reason. How do I remove that '\n' part?

```
print(users, passes)
```

Comment: use module `csv` and you get it without `\n`. And you will no need `split(",")`

Comment: standard method: `i = i.strip()`

Comment: @furas: And just because people often forget, make sure to pass `newline=''` to the `open` call for the file you then iterate using `csv.reader` or the like, so the dialect chooses how to interpret differing forms of newline. But yeah, the only correct way to parse CSV in Python is with the `csv` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strip` to remove unnecessary spaces `\n`s and `\t`s:

```
users = []
passes = []

csvfile = open('upassword.csv', 'r', encoding= 'utf-8')
for i in csvfile:
  i = i.strip()
  x = i.split(',')
  if x[0] != 'username':
    print('username: ', x[0])
    users.append(x[0])
  if x[1] != 'password':
    print('password:', x[1])
    passes.append(x[1])
```

Comment: you need `strip()` also `if x[1].strip() != 'password':`. Simpler would be `i = i.strip()`